# While using Custom View for viewForHeaderInSection disappears when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have used following code

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


           lblStoreName_Header.text =[[itemArr objectAtIndex:section-1] objectForKey:kBRANDNAME];
            return SearchHeaderView;

    }
```

**I HAVE CHECKED THIS QUESTION**

[viewForHeaderInSection disappears when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706207/viewforheaderinsection-disappears-when-scrolling)

Comment: put a break point and check 'SearchHeaderView' should not become nil second time. Seems like your view is not owned by class so its release once it has been used.

Comment: how is possible to do so with custom view

Comment: Just NSLog serachheadrView above the returning the view and check if its printing nil on scrolling.

Comment: what can we do when it returns nil

Comment: First confirm its returning nil, Reason of it becomes nil is it get deallocated as no pointer strongly owned that object.

Answer (score 0):

Because UITableViewHeaderFooterView is reusable like UITableViewCell.

First you need register a UITableViewHeaderFooterView with a identifier.

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"section"];
```

In `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` use `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` to get reusable headerView.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *sectionView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"section"];
    sectionView.textLabel.text = @"ABC";
    return sectionView;
}
```

Comment: how is possible to do so with custom view

Comment: Subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView and register it.